# asp.net mvc is Session available at any point during controller construction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

i am trying to access Session variables in the constructor of a controller and ControllerContext it seems is always null.

When is the earliest the session variables are available?

thanks!

Edit: Example:

in one controller:

```
public HomeController()
    {
        MyClass test =   (MyClass)ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["SessionClass"];
    //ControllerContext always null           
    }
```

when debugging, controllercontext is ALWAYS null.  In the controller whose actionresult redirects to this controller, i have:

```
Session["SessionClass"] = class;

MyClass test = (MyClass )ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["SessionClass"]; 
// this works fine! i can get varibale from session

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

So, at what point is ControllerContext actually set?  When can I access session variables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Override [Initialize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize.aspx):

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    requestContext.HttpContext.Session["blabla"] = "hello"; // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Great, this worked.
Can you please explain why, or post a link to somewhere explaining why?
thanks again!

Comment: Just found out this question is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424548/why-my-session-variables-are-not-available-at-construction-of-a-controller

Answer (score -3):

Session variables are already available in the `constructor call` of your controller.

But those `Sesison[]` variables aren't freely available `anywhere` in your controller class.

---

-> You need to call them either in the constructor or in a method of your controller.

Furthermore those variables should have been set somewhere or their vaues will stay `null`.

According to your example you'll need to set your `Session["SessionClass"]` key somewhere before calling it in the constructor:

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
  Session["SessionClass"] = new MyClass() { // Set your class properties };

  return View((MyClass)Session["SessionClass"]);
}
```

Now we'll unbox that saved value from the session:

```
public HomeController()
{
  MyClass test = (MyClass)Session["SessionClass"];

  // Do stuff with `test` now
}
```

This should work fine within your controller.

Cheers

Comment: hi, i've added code to show how i can't access them in the controller constructor. thanks for your help

Comment: have you tried accessing them only with Session["KEY"].. this has to work.. I just tried it myself.

Comment: perhaps because the controller in which controllercontext is null is inheriting from a base controller i created?