# I want to use session in the asp.net mvc controller constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to Mvc.

Sorry to my english. ^^

I have some question about asp.net MVC session in the controller.

The Scenario things that I want to do is like follows..

1. First of all, My development circumstance is entityframework and mvc3.
2. When Someone logged in each one has different database. So, Each has connect different database.
3. So, Each person has his own session value which is database connection string. So far so good.
4. I have simple database Repository and at the each repository's constructor can change database connection.
5. At controller which calls Repository class, I need session value. But As I know Controller's construction can't keep session value. right?
6. I want your good advice. Thanks in advance.

Code samples are below:

```
public class MasterRepository 
{
    DBEntities _db;

    public MasterRepository(string con)
    {
        _db = new DBEntities(con);
    }

}

public class TestController : Controller
{

    private string con;

    MasterRepository _db;

    public TestController()
    {
    _db = new MasterRepository(Session["conn"].ToString()); //  Session is null I want to solve this Part...
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        string con = Session["conn"].ToString(); // Session is assigned.

        return View();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed out the "service" part of the controller - service - repository pattern:

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2008/04/24/what-purpose-does-the-repository-pattern-have.aspx

But when you go down this path you will probably also need to learn IoC as well.

Then your code would look more like:

```
public class MasterRepository 
{
    public Foo GetAllFoo()
    {
        return ObjectContextManager.GetObjectContext().AsQueryable().ToList();
    }  
}

public class MasterService 
{
    MasterRepository _repository;   
    public MasterService(MasterRepository repository) // use IoC
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public Foo GetAllFoo()
    {
        return _repository.GetAllFoo();
    }    
}    

public class TestController : Controller
{  
    MasterService _service;
    public TestController(MasterService service) // use IoC
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {    
        var model _service.GetAllFoo();   
        return View(model);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thank you JK!!!

But That's not what I want.

I just want to use my session value to my controller so I want to keep my database connection in a controller's contructor.

The point is not set to an controller's contructor.

MasterRepository _db;    
public TestController()    
{    
   //  Session is null I want to solve this Part...
   _db = new MasterRepository(Session["conn"].ToString());     
}

I want to use _db variable to my Testcontroller.

If impossible set session value to controller's constructor, Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

These should explain what's happening to cause Session to be null, and give you a few possible solution options:

- [Is ASP.NET MVC Session available at any point durign controller construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425566/asp-net-mvc-is-session-available-at-any-point-durign-controller-construction)
- [Why my session variables are not available at construction of a Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424548/why-my-session-variables-are-not-available-at-construction-of-a-controller)
- [Session null in ASP.Net MVC Controller Constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889516/session-null-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-constructors)